# Creating a custom dialog container using CdkDialogContainer

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, angular-cdk, flowbite

I am writing an Angular (14.2.0) service to display a Tailwind/Flowbite [dialog](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/modal/) (modal in Flowbite language). It seems I must create a custom [Angular CDK dialog container](https://material.angular.io/cdk/dialog/overview) to maintain the DOM structure outline on the Flowbite page and to apply the classes correctly.

I don't know how to create and use such a container though, the CDK documentation is not particularly clear.

My service code looks like this:

```
import { Dialog } from '@angular/cdk/dialog';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FlowbiteService {

  constructor(public dialog: Dialog) {}

  openDialog<C>(component: ComponentType<C>) {
    return this.dialog.open(component, {
      backdropClass: 'dialog-backdrop',
      panelClass: 'dialog-panel',
      container: DialogContainerComponent
    });
  }

}
```

...and my `DialogContainerComponent` is very simple, looking like this (the CSS is not really important):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-container',
  templateUrl: './dialog-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-container.component.css']
})
export class DialogContainerComponent extends CdkDialogContainer {
}
```

However, calling the service yields a `app-dialog-container` element, but it has no children in the DOM when rendered.

I thought perhaps the content would be projected, so I added `<ng-content></ng-content>` into the markup for `DialogContainerComponent`, but this has no effect.

How do I correctly create and use my custom CDK dialog container? The documentation gives no example really.

Comment: You need to re-implement the `DialogContainerComponent` class. This is what the official site says: `This approach requires more code up-front, but it allows you to customize the DOM structure and behavior of the container around the dialog content. `

Comment: Yeah I did read that, but what does the class need to do??

Comment: You need to copy and modify the code from the source code, then add the `cdkPortalOutlet` to your HTML. I think you had answered your own question.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I decided to look through the source code and found that the template of the `cdk-dialog-container` contained this:

```
<ng-template cdkPortalOutlet></ng-template>
```

I put this is my own template and now it's working. Sorted.

Comment: Would you mind posting a working example? I'm having trouble with the call to super() in my derived class, and if I remove it - no content is rendered in the cdkPortalOutlet.
So far as I can tell this is the only resource of information on this topic, outside the docs.

Comment: That documentation from CDK Dialog needs to seriously get updated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after having struggled myself with it, I'll give here a simple example to understand the basics. Pay attention to the imports, they all come from `@angular/cdk` dependency.

##### `somewhere-in-your-app.component.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Dialog } from '@angular/cdk/dialog';
import { MyDialog } from './my-dialog/my-dialog';
import { MyDialogContainer } from './my-dialog/my-dialog-container';

@Component({
  selector: 'somewhere-in-your-app',
  template: '<button (click)="openDialog()">Open dialog</button>',
})
export class SomewhereInYourAppComponent {

  constructor(
    private readonly cdkDialog: Dialog,
  ) {}

  openDialog() {
    this.cdkDialog.open(MyDialog, {
      container: MyDialogContainer,
    });
  }

}
```

##### `my-dialog.module.ts`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogModule } from '@angular/cdk/dialog';
import { MyDialogContainer } from './my-dialog-container';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DialogModule,  // Needed for the `cdkPortalOutlet` directive
  ],

  declarations: [
    MyDialogContainer,
  ],
})
export class MyDialogModule {}
```

##### `my-dialog-container.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDialogContainer } from '@angular/cdk/dialog';

@Component({
  template: '<ng-template cdkPortalOutlet></ng-template>',
})
export class MyDialogContainer extends CdkDialogContainer {}
```

##### `my-dialog.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: '<p>This is my actual dialog.</p>',
})
export class MyDialog {}
```